# How to find total time difference bwteen date range

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have created a procedure which returns time difference in minutes between 2 time i.e. ShiftStartTime, ShiftEndtime.

Now problem is that if i pass 2 date ranges then how i will calculate total shiftTime between those 2 dates e.g.  TimeDifference returns me 480 min for today but i want to find total ShiftDifference for 3 days or more, then how i will add TimeDifference for more than 1 day ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetShiftTotalDuration

 @ShiftID int = 9,
 @FromDate DateTime,
 @ToDate DateTime

AS
BEGIN

    Declare @TimeDifference int
    Declare @ShiftStartTime time
    Declare @ShiftEndTime time

    Set @ShiftStartTime = (Select DeparmentShiftsHistory.StartTime from DeparmentShiftsHistory 
                           where DeparmentShiftsHistory.Shift_ID= 9)
    Set @ShiftEndTime = (Select DeparmentShiftsHistory.EndTime from DeparmentShiftsHistory
                           where DeparmentShiftsHistory.Shift_ID= 9)
    Set @TimeDifference = (Select DATEDIFF(mi,@ShiftStartTime,@ShiftEndTime)) --Returns time difference in seconds



END
GO
```

Comment: U didn't use the input parameters fromdate & todate. If am not not wrong u need to add that in where clause of departmentshifts table and ur question is not clear!!.

Answer (score 0):

> I will calculate total shiftTime between those 2 dates

You mention that you will calculate difference between two dates but in your code you declare the variables as  `time`

```
Declare @ShiftStartTime time
Declare @ShiftEndTime time
```

Thus `DATEDIFF(mi,@ShiftStartTime,@ShiftEndTime)` only the difference between the times not the dates

If you want to get the difference between dates you need use `datetime` datatype

On a side note, you have declared input parameters which have not been used in the proocedure as mentioned by [Pradeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3349551/pradeep)